# react website scaling down on mobile device with build

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm encountering a scaling issue specifically within the build of my ReactJS application when viewed on mobile devices. The problem seems to persist despite my attempts to configure the viewport meta tag and implement responsive design techniques.

The issue I'm facing within the build:

- Excessive scaling down on mobile devices, making the content too small
- Configured `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; viewport-fit=cover; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=no" />` in the `public/index.html`
- Reviewed React components for layout and used relative units for sizing

[ISSUE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H22si.png)

This issue occurs only within the built version of the application and not in development. Are there considerations or differences in handling the viewport or responsive design within a built React application compared to the development environment?

I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot or adjust configurations within the build specifically to resolve this scaling problem on mobile devices. Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

I've already tried:

- Setting the viewport meta tag in `public/index.html` with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; viewport-fit=cover; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=no" />`
- Reviewing my React components for fixed-width elements and using relative units for layout
- Testing on various mobile devices using browser developer tools

Comment: provide some good examples or code to generate this issue.

Comment: Despite setting the viewport to match the device's width, it appears that the content is not adapting appropriately and remains fixed at 980px. This issue is evident across various mobile devices, where the content does not adjust to the expected smaller width.

I've ensured that there are no fixed-width elements within my React components, and I've used relative units for sizing. However, the problem persists within the built version of the ReactJS application.